# Moving from a Mac to Ubuntu for Rails development, what are the ramifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Are there any gotchas or things to watch out for if I move from a Mac to a Ubuntu environment?

Any major configuration issues?  Or should things work pretty much the same once I figure out how to install things? (seems installation is easier on Ubuntu anyhow).

Comment: If your using RVM you shouldn't have any major issues. There's great Ubuntu support for most tools I've used so far, in dev and production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the gotchas for setting up Rails are for Mac :-)

Stick to Ubuntu and make sure to use RVM to set up your Ruby environment. Do not use `sudo apt-get` to install rails, and after RVM is installed avoid using `sudo` altogether when installing gems (eg. `gem install rails`).

Only complaint is that gedit is not as slick as Textmate, but check out [the gmate plugin](https://github.com/gmate/gmate).

Comment: Sublime Text 2 is also another good editor alternative (http://www.sublimetext.com/download).

Answer (score 1):

The biggest gain of switching ubuntu, imho, is you don't have to deal with osx specific headaches of setting up dev-server environment.

I am pretty happy with ubuntu, a possible alternative to gmate might be sublime text 2. 
It can be configured with vim mode, emacs mode, etc.